# I implemented the Interface but I get "does not implement interface member"

Tags: c#, class, oop

I am receiving this error:

> `CalculatorCalories` does not implement interface member
>   `ICalculatorCalories.GetIndex`

But I implemented the interface's method:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public interface ICalculatorCalories
    {
        int GetIndex { get; }
    }

    public partial class CalculatorCalories : Form, ICalculatorCalories
    {
        public CalculatorCalories()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int GetIndex(int growthC, int sex)
        {
            int index = growthC - 100 - ((growthC - 150) / sex);
            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetIndex` is a property! Not a method

Answer (score 4):

The problem is because the interface defines a readonly property, where the implementation's `GetIndex` is a method.  You need to change one or the other.

Presumably, edit your interface to:

```
public interface ICalculatorCalories
{
    int GetIndex(int growthC, int sex);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `ICalculatorCalories` you've defined `GetIndex` as a getter property instead of the function that you've implemented. In order for the class to implement the interface, the signature of the methods/properties must match.

Suggest fixing the interface:

```
public interface ICalculatorCalories
{
    int GetIndex(int growthC, int sex);
}
```